# AWSやGCPにZabbixなどサードパーティーの監視ツールを導入する意義を教えて下さい

Tags: aws, google-cloud, zabbix

クラウドサービスについて全く無知の為、教えて下さい。

AWSとGCPの環境にサーバー（インスタンス？）を構築します。
それらに対して、オンプレミスで通常行うような死活監視やリソース監視、ログ監視、プロセス監視等を行いたいと思います。

調べたところ、AWSにはCloudWatch、GCPにはStackdriverという機能があるようですが、それで充足できるならサードパーティーのツールを導入する必要は無いと思います。

ただ、Zabbix等を調べると、AWS等にも対応したとの記述があります。

クラウドサービス標準の機能だけでなく、あえてZabbix等を導入することにどのようなメリットがあるのでしょうか？
クラウドサービスの機能ではできないことがあるのでしょうか？

自分でも調べましたが、どうにもネットの情報だけではわかりません。

どなたか是非アドバイスをお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

Zabbixのような監視ツールを既存の監視ツールが存在するIaaS環境に導入することについては、いくつかのメリット、デメリットがあります。以下、それぞれ列挙してみます。

## メリット

### 柔軟に設定できる

ベンダの提供するものは、大抵導入が簡単な分監視項目が少なく、思い通りの設定ができなかったりします。
その点、自分で監視ツールを導入することで、欲しい項目を取得し、それぞれの状態を比較することが容易になります。

### サードパーティである

@あとわいと 氏も指摘する通り、AWSとGCPそれぞれに環境を用意（マルチクラウドと言います）する場合、ベンダの提供する監視ツールで確認できる項目はそれぞれのツールに依存してしまいます。このため、同じ項目を取得することができなかったり、欲しい項目を取得できなかったりします。そして、環境を増やす毎に使い方や設定を学ぶ必要があります。一方、サードパーティ製のツールを使うことで、一回覚えてしまえば全部の環境で使い回すことが可能になります。

## デメリット

### 監視ツールのリソースを用意し、実行し、監視をする必要がある（場合がある）

監視ツールの種類や構成にもよりますが、大抵の場合別にインスタンスを立ててそこで実行し、もし監視ツールが突然死んだ場合の対処をする、というような手間が発生します。一方、CloudWatchやStackDriverはマネージドサービスであるため、各ベンダが動作を保障してくれます。

### 監視ツール用の知識が必要である

ツールに関わらず、導入から設定、実行までにある程度の知識を必要とします。その点、CloudWatchやStackDriverは、ほぼ自動で監視を開始することができます。

### 別のツールとの連携が比較的簡単ではない

CloudWatchではAWS SNSと連携してエラー時に通知、ということが数クリックで構成可能です。StackDriverでもおそらく可能でしょう。

各種監視ツールで同様のことをするには、一旦AWSのプラグインを入れ、通知用の設定を書く、などの必要があるかと存じます。

Answer (score 0):

具体的にZabbixで監視したい。やりたいことを列挙してクラウドウォッチをベンチマークしてはいかがでしょうか。監視要件もわからない段階で、メリット、デメリットはわかりません。逆に「何したいかわからないけど、とりあえず監視したい」という話であれば、まず運用要件と非機能要件の整理が必要になります。
さきに仕掛けをきめてから、「あれもやりたい、これもやりたい」となると、2度、3度作らなくてはならなくなるのです。

さて、上述の前提の上でざっと思いつく利点とか、Zabbix使いたくなるポイントとしては

- 既存のオンプレミスシステムで利用している監視抑止、監視対象の定義を流用したい。

  - 膨大な情報のなかで「何を監視するのか、閾値をどうするのか」などは割と設計の面倒な、ノウハウ集です。
- 閾値監視、キーワード監視などを簡単に実現したい。

  - CloudWatchって監視用の仕掛けはLambdaなどで実装する必要なかったでしたっけ？
- 使い慣れた仕組みをそのまま利用したい。

  - 現在Zabbixを利用している場合、ノウハウ、仕掛け、運用手順はそのままに、使い続けたくなるわけです。。

…ここまで書いて「AWSとGCPの環境にサーバー」というお話に気づきました。。

よくもわるくも、「すべてを同一クラウドに閉じ込める」ことができればCloudWatchでよいでしょう、一歩外に出たいと考えると、使い物になりません。たとえば、既存システムの一部にAWSを組み込んで利用。運用はZabbix & Cloud Watchとかすると、運用の煩雑さからコストが跳ね上がりますよね。。。同様に、AWS/GCPとまたがったシステムに、それぞれの監視では運用コストが馬鹿にならなくなるのです。。それぞれの仕掛けのための準備をするとか。。。もうアフォかと。。。
であれば、利用するクラウドによらない、Zabbixのようなツールの利用はとても合理的な選択になりえます。。